# Java: JNA SystemParametersInfo parameters type

Tags: java, pointers, jna

I only started to experiment with JNA, and stuck trying to call this function w/o exception
Native prototype:

```
BOOL WINAPI SystemParametersInfo(
  __in     UINT uiAction,
  __in     UINT uiParam,
  __inout  PVOID pvParam,
  __in     UINT fWinIni
);
```

I've suggested such JNA equivalent:

```
public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

        boolean SystemParametersInfo(
                UINT_PTR uiAction,
                UINT_PTR uiParam,
                Pointer pvParam,
                UINT_PTR fWinIni
        );
        public static final int SPI_GETCLEARTYPE = 0x1048;
        public static final int SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0073;
}
```

And the question is how to call it with different pvParam types using pointer?
for example SPI_GETCLEARTYPE (where it's BOOL) and SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER (where it's char[])

Comment: One way to do it is to overload your `User32.SystemParametersInfo` method where `pvParam` (take note the `_inout` macro) is of a reference type (since Java parameters are pass-by-value). The trick to create a reference type in JNA is by using an array data type (except for JNA `ByReference` types). So, pvParam can be `PointerByReference`, `boolean[]`, `char[]`, etc. Then, access the data by its element index e.g. `pvParam[0]` (depending on what its data is)

Comment: oh thanks,already resolved this myself 3 weeks earlier.
As it turned out the main reason i couldn't made this working is misunderstanding how JNA type Pointer works. Will provide self-answer a bit later

Comment: I think its now a bit later ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved myself so the mapping:

```
    public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class,
            new HashMap<Object, Object>() {
            {
                put(OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
                put(OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
            }
        });
        public static final int SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0073;
        public static final int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING = 114;
        boolean SystemParametersInfo(
                int uiAction,
                int uiParam,
                Pointer pvParam,
                int fWinIni
        );
    }
```

and the usage:

```
IntByReference intPtr = new IntByReference();
//that's the place where i'm stuck trying to initialize with Pointer constructor
Pointer ptr = new Memory(Pointer.SIZE * 256);
User32.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(User32.SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0,intPtr.getPointer(), 0);
User32.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(User32.SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER,256, ptr, 0);
```