# Getting the current wallpaper file name in Windows 7

Tags: java, winapi

Is there any way to get the current wallpaper file name in Windows 7 (perhaps through a dll call) when it's shuffling randomly between many wallpapers?

I have many backgrounds set to randomly change after a few minutes and I would like to remove ones that come up that I don't like from the list.  It would save me a lot of time if I could just ask windows what the filename of the wallpaper is that it's currently displaying.

Comment: Have you tried SystemParametersInfo() yet?

Comment: how do i do that?  Do i need to write a program for it? Does it work in Java?

Comment: Ok i googled it and based on the results it looks like you can set the wallpaper with it but you can't get the filename.  That was a good suggestion though.  Thanks.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Sure you can, SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER.

Comment: Oh cool, i'm not sure how i missed that.  Do you know how I can call this method from Java (likely using JNI?)?  Is there a command line executable I could call to give me this information?

Comment: JNA is easier. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132431/java-jna-systemparamatersinfo-parameters-type

Comment: I can't find a place to download this.  All the download links i found are broken.  Is JNA still being used/supported/developed?

Comment: Ok I found a place to download the library.  Thanks David for that link.  I got it to work with that example.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the only problem is that it doesn't give me the file name from my theme directory.  Ie. i have a set of wallpapers that get rotated randomly and it just copies the file to C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg and that's the path it gives me.  I want the original path and file name.  Is there any way to get that?

Comment: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/desktop-background-file-location-right-click-menu-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit old question, but there is another solution to the problem:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo The path to the current Desktop background image is:
echo.
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperSource
pause
exit
```

Hope it helps to somebody.

BTW: how could I get that return string into parameter of delete?